# Sharepoint 2013 Lists forms

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, custom-form

How can I hide and show fields in lists forms using PowerShell

Comment: you could use CSOM within powershell and set field's ShowInNewForm  property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To hide a specific field in New/Edit form via PowerShell, check the below script**

```
$rootWeb = Get-SPWeb http://your site
#Get an reference to the  list
$list=$rootWeb.Lists["your list"]                           
#Get a reference to the created field
$Field = $list.Fields["yourfield"]
#show the column in New and Edit form
$Field.ShowInEditForm = $false
$Field.ShowInNewForm = $false        
#Push field Update
$Field.Update()
```

**To show specific field in New/Edit form via PowerShell, check the below script**

```
$rootWeb = Get-SPWeb http://your site
#Get an reference to the  list
$list=$rootWeb.Lists["your list"]                           
#Get a reference to the created field
$Field = $list.Fields["yourfield"]
#Hide the column in New and Edit form
$Field.ShowInEditForm = $true
$Field.ShowInNewForm = $true
#Push field Update
$Field.Update()
```